# MAKEFILES variable environment

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

How to use `MAKEFILES` variable environment? I writing in a bash `MAKEFILES=/home/toker/mymake`, but if I'm running a `/home/toker/bundocode/gettingstart/testMF/Makefile` then `/home/toker/mymake` doesn't executed. When I'm type `$MAKEFILES` in the bash then `bash: /home/toker/mymake: Permission denied` is displayed.

Comment: If `.../testMF/Makefile` is a makefile, and `/usr/toker/mymake` is also a makefile, then *which one are you trying to use?*

Comment: @Beta The follwoing ling http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKEFILES-Variable said that _If the environment variable MAKEFILES is defined, make considers its value as a list of names (separated by whitespace) of additional makefiles to be read before the others._. First I cant set the value of variable environment which separated by whitespace. Second I set this variable to the makefile which I want to processed before the other. It is `/home/toker/mymake`, but there is no processed.

Comment: You can absolutely set a variable to a value containing whitespace.  Just quote it: `export MAKEFILES="/some/file /some/other/file"`.  As for why it doesn't work, I expect you forgot to export the variable; this is something you have to understand about the shell, not make.  If you run `env | grep MAKEFILES` do you see your assignment output?  You should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MAKEFILES` variable contains one or more makefiles, not the make program.  From the above messages it looks like `mymake` is a make program you're trying to run.  The shell decides what programs to run (by looking in directories listed in the `$PATH` environment variable) and the shell doesn't pay any special attention to the `MAKEFILES` variable.  Only once make is running does it look at the `MAKEFILES` variable to see what other makefiles it might want to parse.

What is in the `/usr/toker/mymake` file?  What do you mean by *running a .../Makefile*?  One typically *runs* make, not a makefile.  Then make reads in the makefile.  There are ways to change a makefile to be executable but I don't think that's what you're looking for here.

ETA:

If the file `/usr/toker/mymake` is actually a makefile (BTW, convention typically uses `.mk` extensions to denote makefiles although there's no really official extension), then you can do this:

```
$ cat /usr/toker/mymake
$(info loaded /usr/toker/mymake)
foo: ; @echo building $@

$ export MAKEFILES=/usr/toker/mymake

$ cat Makefile
bar: foo ; @echo building $@

$ make
loaded /usr/toker/mymake
building foo
building bar
```

If you can show an example of exactly what you did (show the makefile and the commands you typed and the results you got) and explain what you don't understand about it, then we can see much more accurately what's going on than by you trying to describe it in words).

Comment: _What is in the /usr/toker/mymake file?_ It is makefile, not make program.

Comment: _What do you mean by running a .../Makefile?_ I mean that I'm execute  `make` command.